# Регулярное выражение(только латинские буквы и цифры)

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Почему это регулярное выражение пропускает, допустим, латинские буквы плюс кавычки или цифры плюс русские буквы? Только русские буквы и кавычки не пропускает.

```
if (!preg_match("/[A-Za-z0-9]/", $cod)) {
exit ("<p>Код должен состоять из латинских букв и цифр! <input name='back' type='button' value='Вернуться назад' onclick='javascript:self.back();'></p>");
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Это неверное регулярное выражение, вам необходимо указать границы строки

```
    preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/",$cod)
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому, что ваше условие соответствует "в строке нет ни латинских букв ни цифр" а вам видимо нужно "есть хотя бы один символ, который не латинская буква и не цифра"

```
if (preg_match("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", $cod))
```

Comment: Она не это имела в виду, если посмотреть в функцию exit() то можно понять, что нужно. У нее плохо сформулирован вопрос.

Comment: Да, вы правы